# Reverse Proxy Nginx not changing the url before GET

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, vps

I've been trying to create a reverse proxy for a vps I have for my website. For one of my dashboards, I'm trying to pull data from a public api I got online https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=1. This is my server block

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name {{my_ip}};
root /var/www/mydomain.com/public_html;
index index.html;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location /alternative {
    proxy_pass https://api.alternative.me/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}
}
```

I used angular, so in my service class, I have

```
  fng: string = '/alternative/fng/?limit=1';
  getFng(): Observable<any[]> {
       return this.http.get<any[]>(this.fng, httpOptions);
  }
```

I want to reverse proxy so that when I am on my website dashboard which has a chart that calls to the api, my reverse proxy will change the url from https://{{my_api}}/alternative/fng/?limit=1, to https://api.alternative.me/fng/?limit=1. I'm not sure how else to configure the file to get it to work? Can someone let me know if there's something I'm missing? Thanks.